# Check Teamspeak status via Shellscript (Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script for Ubuntu, which checks the Teamspeak-server status and reacts to them.

This is my actual version:

```
a=$(sh /home/teamspeak3/ts3/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh status)
echo "$a"
if [ "$a" -ne "Server is running"]
then
echo "..."
fi
exit 0
```

This is my actual output (and problem):

```
user1234@euve252903:~$ ./keepAlive.sh
Server is running
./keepAlive.sh: line 8: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

(The text "Server is running" is the output from echo "$a").

I don't get the reason, why the syntax error appears...
I checked the file for MSDOS-ending signs.

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a space before the last bracket in your if statement

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(sh /home/teamspeak3/ts3/teamspeak3-
server_linux_amd64/ts3server_startscript.sh status)
echo "$a"
if [ "$a" -ne "Server is running" ]; then
    echo "..."
fi
exit 0
```

Also, I'd recommend adding a shebang and lastly, running the script in debug mode (bash -x) to find out what's wrong. If neither one of those work for you, try [Shell Check](https://www.shellcheck.net/), at least for syntax errors that is.